# Combining 3 columns of the same variable into one column for tabulation in Stata

Tags: stata

This is a very simple question but I am stumped even after searching for answers. I have a survey, and one of the questions on the survey asks for methods of coping for calamities, and it gives room for up to 3 answers. There are 16 possible responses (answer codes), which I have already labeled. However I'm trying to combine the 3 columns in the way that one would just cut and paste the responses from column 2 and 3, right below column 1, in Excel. I tried reshaping, but it seems like there has to be another variable like an id that goes along with it. I understand this is a very simple process, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: No; this isn't a simple question because you just give a word description of your data and assume that it's transparent. Much, much better to show a sample of your data with example values and variable names. Further, this is stated to be about Stata, but you make minimal effort to use Stata terms to describe your problem. You also give no precise code that you tried. That's probably why you got down votes (but it wasn't me down voting).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just started using Stata a couple days ago and discovered this website today, so I'll be sure to be more specific next time posting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a unique identifier `patid`; if you don't you'll need to create one;

```
gen t=1
gen patid=sum(t)
```

works. You also need to name the three variables so they all end in a number e.g. `v1 v2 v3`. Then the following should work:

```
preserve
keep patid v1 v2 v3
reshape v,i(patid)
tab v
restore
```

The `preserve` and `restore` mean that whilst you have printed the required table you have still got the original database without the `reshape` on it.